# How do I prevent form from disappearing after user submits?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a form in a modal (bootstrap4 theme for a wordpress site) in php. After a user submits the form in this modal, the page "reloads" and the "Form submitted successfully" message replaces the form. This means that when a user clicks the button to open the modal again, there is no form there; just a success message.  How do I prevent this behaviour? I want to "reset" the form for a user to a clean form so they can submit again and again each time.
This is the site code in context: https://github.com/bettersg/mediaspin/blob/master/articlemodal.php

And this is the form itself:

```
<div class="fade modal pg-show-modal" id="article_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="article_modal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <?php $mailer = new PG_Article_Form_Mailer(); ?>
    <?php $mailer->process( array(
            'form_id' => 'article_form_mailer_id',
            'send_to_email' => true,
            'save_to_post_type' => true,
            'post_type' => 'article',
            'captcha' => true,
            'captcha_key' => get_theme_mod( 'captcha_key' ),
            'captcha_secret' => get_theme_mod( 'captcha_secret' )
    ) ); ?>
    <?php if( !$mailer->processed || $mailer->error) : ?>
    <form action="#" class="wordpress-ajax-form" method="post" onsubmit="event.stopImmediatePropagation();event.stopPropagation();">

    <div class="modal-content" id="article_form_mailer_id">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="article_modallabel"><?php _e( 'New Article Submission for Current Issue', 'mediaspintheme' ); ?></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <?php global $post;   ?>
            <input type="hidden" placeholder="CurrentIssue" name="issue" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"></input>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="form-control-label">
                    <?php _e( 'Link to news article (not social media or forum post) that spins it:', 'mediaspintheme' ); ?>
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="article1" required placeholder="https://linkhere.com (do not post social media or forum links)" name="article1" value="<?php echo ( isset( $_POST['article1'] ) ? $_POST['article1'] : '' ); ?>">
            </div>
             
            <div class="g-recaptcha" style="margin:10px 0;" data-sitekey="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'captcha_key' ) ?>"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="article_form_mailer_id" value="1"/>
              
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                <?php _e( 'Close', 'mediaspintheme' ); ?>
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <?php _e( 'SUBMIT', 'mediaspintheme' ); ?>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
        
    <?php endif; ?>
   
</div>
</div>

<?php if( $mailer->processed ) : ?>
    <?php  echo  $mailer->message;  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I suspect it is because of the way the if statement ( `<?php if( !$mailer->processed || $mailer->error) : ?>`) is framed around the form but i'm not sure what the correct approach is. Any advice on how to change the if statement or to move it such that it does not cause the form to disappear after successful submission?

The form submits properly and everything works. But this interface quirk is annoying.

Comment: I understand the question, but not what you want to achieve. After the user submit the form and page get reloaded, the form has to be there again. But you want to show ALSO a success message or not?

Comment: Yes, @Raffobaffo that's correct. I want the form to be there first. The user completes and submits the form. The page reloads after submit as per php form handling. And then the form is reset with blank fields, but the success message is on top of that form. **"Your form was submitted successfully. Submit another input below:"**

Comment: Ok cool. I'll write you an answer.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using if in the correct way. In your structure, the form is displayed only when there has been an error or is never been sent. To solve, refactor as follows:

```
<?php if( $mailer->processed ) : ?>
    <?php  echo  $mailer->message;  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="fade modal pg-show-modal" id="article_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="article_modal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <?php $mailer = new PG_Article_Form_Mailer(); ?>
    <?php $mailer->process( array(
            'form_id' => 'article_form_mailer_id',
            'send_to_email' => true,
            'save_to_post_type' => true,
            'post_type' => 'article',
            'captcha' => true,
            'captcha_key' => get_theme_mod( 'captcha_key' ),
            'captcha_secret' => get_theme_mod( 'captcha_secret' )
    ) ); ?>
    <form action="#" class="wordpress-ajax-form" method="post" onsubmit="event.stopImmediatePropagation();event.stopPropagation();">

    <div class="modal-content" id="article_form_mailer_id">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="article_modallabel"><?php _e( 'New Article Submission for Current Issue', 'mediaspintheme' ); ?></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <?php global $post;   ?>
            <input type="hidden" placeholder="CurrentIssue" name="issue" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"></input>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message-text" class="form-control-label">
                    <?php _e( 'Link to news article (not social media or forum post) that spins it:', 'mediaspintheme' ); ?>
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="article1" required placeholder="https://linkhere.com (do not post social media or forum links)" name="article1" value="<?php echo ( isset( $_POST['article1'] ) ? $_POST['article1'] : '' ); ?>">
            </div>
             
            <div class="g-recaptcha" style="margin:10px 0;" data-sitekey="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'captcha_key' ) ?>"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="article_form_mailer_id" value="1"/>
              
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                <?php _e( 'Close', 'mediaspintheme' ); ?>
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <?php _e( 'SUBMIT', 'mediaspintheme' ); ?>
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's partially what I thought, but this is code generated by one of those apps (pinegrow) so i didn't want to change it without checking. anyway, turns out their default boilerplate code for forms has this weird behaviour.

Comment: Great. If it solved mark it as answered else feel free to ask more

Answer (score 0):

You could deal with jQuery and AJAX.

```
$('.wordpress-ajax-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    // Prevent page reloading
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'youScript.php',
        data: { 
            'youWillGetThisValueInPhpWithThisName': $('.your-input').val(),
             // others inputs
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: thanks - but even with ajax i will need to redo the `if` statement logic for the php above. any advice?